# If two cells match, return value from third

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-match

Here's a simple explanation of what I'm having trouble with.

Column A: List of 2300 order numbers
Column B: Email Address associated with an order number
Column C: List of 100 specific order numbers that I need the email address for

So, I'm looking to search column A for a value that matches C, and return the email address from column B in a new column (D).

The current formula almost works, but instead of returning the email address where A matched C, it returns the email address from the same row.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C2,A:A,0)),B2)
```

Essentially I just need B2 in the formula above to return the value from the same line that matched.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think what you want is something like:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))
```

I should mention that [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) checks the *position* at which the value can be found within A:A (given the `0`, or FALSE, parameter, it looks only for an exact match and given its nature, only the first instance found) then [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) returns the value at that position within B:B.

Comment: In this particular case it might have been easier to use =VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,FALSE) but there appear to be strong arguments for using match / index routinely  http://www.mbaexcel.com/excel/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup/

Comment: I agree with your line of reasoning @pnuts - maybe I will switch to using index / match in future!

Comment: @pnuts Can you answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478990/how-to-get-the-names-of-the-regions-from-maxmind-data

Comment: This is great - Exactly what I need :) Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0))),"",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C2,A:A,0)))
```

Will return the answer you want and also remove the `#N/A` result that would appear if you couldn't find a result due to it not appearing in your lookup list.

Ross

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is write an IF condition in the column d like this:

```
=IF(A1=C1;B1;" ")
```

After that just apply this formula to all rows above that one.

Comment: I may have done a poor job in my explanation. This would be exactly what I needed if I only needed to pull data from one row, but the columns didn't line up. Thank you though!