# If two cells in two columns are associated with each other, do something with a third cell/column

Tags: excel

Here is a simplified explanation of what I'm having trouble with in Excel:

Column A: "Type" column that I have setup a drop-down menu to select choices from on each row (4 total choices to select from).

Column B: Notes to explain the "Type" selected in column A

Column C: Start Time

Column D: End Time

Column E: This column sums up the total hours elapsed between C and D

Column F: Total Amounts of time for each selection in Column A

I'm basically trying to create a formula in Column F to say if Column A equals a certain "Type", sum the value(s) in Column E associate with that "Type". I'm trying to repeat this on a separate row in column F for each of the choices available in Column A.

I tried using this question, but the values in my columns A and E are not going to match.
[If two cells match, return value from third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request: To show total hours by type as reflected in the figure below.

[image]

If my understanding is correct then enter this formula in `F2` and copy down:

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$13,$A2,$E$1:$E$13)`

Also format the cells in column `F` as `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: Thank you very much. After a bit of tweaking, it worked perfectly! I ended up with this, as my choices in column A are linked to a table on another tab:

=SUMIF($A$24:$A$37, 'Non-Scheduled List'!A1, $E$24:$E$37)