# Excel Formula to fetch data from corresponding cells of a search result

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a tab in excel with employee details. Column B is first name, column C is last name,Column  H is their employment status ( LEFT, EMPLOYED ETC)

I want a formula in next tab  to fetch the data of column H of a given name i want to search for.

Lets say in the 2nd tab, i put name John Doe, Sam Bravo, Leah Casey and another 25 names. On the right handside cells of each name i entered, i need the employment status to appear. I have a database of 18000+ employees. So a formula for this will help a lot. Many thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear can you edit it to explain what you want ? Thanks

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: @RedaMaachi - I think that the phrase '**I want a formula ...**' shows very clearly what the OP wants.

Comment: I have looked at the suggestions you have given me , it is not the same to what i am looking for. Can you please help?