# Output category based on multiple inputs

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 combinations o triplets, each with a name attached to them. For example:

Category a = 1,2,3

Category b = 3,1,2

etc...

Each value in the triplet is either 1, 2 or 3.

I need to be able to input 3 values (also 1,2 or 3) into 3 cells, and I need the corresponding category to be displayed next to them (based on the 8 hard coded variants).

For example: if I were to enter 3 1 2 into the three cells, "Category b" would show up in the 4th cell.

Here is a screenshot of what I need:

[image]

The yellow cells are hard coded.

I have a long list of green cells.

I need to calculate the category in the blue cells based on the green cells.

Comment: mock up some data with expected outcome.

Comment: @ScottCraner I just did, do you need more?

Comment: `Index/Match` with multiple criteria?  Also, are the `1,2,3` in the category names in the same cell, or separate cells?

Comment: Yup need more; a table with cell references and what you have tried.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have added a screenshot :)

Comment: @BruceWayne I have added a screenshot

Comment: [`Index/Match` with multiple criteria](https://www.deskbright.com/excel/index-match-multiple-criteria/) is one way to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: Updated screenshot with cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this in E2:

```
 =INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($G$2:$G$9)/(($H$2:$H$9=B2)*($I$2:$I$9=C2)*($J$2:$J$9=D2)),1))
```

Then copy down

[image]