# How can I transpose a data set by doing a double lookup?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is what I have now.

[image]

This is the way I want to see the data.

[image]

It's a pretty small data set.  I'm trying to figure out a way to transpose the data based on a double lookup.  I think it will require some kind of vlookup and index/match, or some kind of row/column offset.  I tried a few ideas, but can't seem to get this resolved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: What happened to the count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a helper column. If you have your data in Column `A:B`, enter this formula `=A2&B2` in cell `C2` and drag it to the bottom.
then if your new table start at cell `F1`, please enter this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$1700,MATCH($F2&G$1,$C$2:$C$1700,0),IF(FIND(G$1,$C2,1)>0,1,0)),"")` in Cell `G2` and drag it beneath whole table.

[image]