# How to get ID numbers based on multiple criteria in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am dealing with the following situation in Excel. I have a table as shown below (range is arbitrary).

[image: Data: Range is arbitrary]

I want to know if there is any function that I can use to get the ID's that :

- **worked more than 8 hours, and**
- **acceptance rate for them is greater than 85, and**
- **satisfaction of customer rate is greater than 4?**

I know I can get this simply by adding filters but I was wondering what is the best approach?

Should I create a customized table and add all my criteria and then do a `VLOOKUP`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: vlookup will return only the first that meets the criteria.  See here for some possible approaches:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without Table

**1. Define this four `Names`: (ctrl+F3)**

Below:

- (I)

Name: `ID`

Refers to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$999))`

- (II)

Name: `Hours`

Refers to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$999))`

- (III)

Name: `SatisfactionRate`

Refers to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$999))`

- (IV)

Name: `AcceptanceRate`

Refers to: `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$F$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$999))`

**2. Write this array formula**

**Case1:**

- select the results container range.
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after
  entering this formula.

`=INDEX(ID,SMALL(IF(AND(Hours>8,SatisfactionRate>4,AcceptanceRate>85),ROW(ID)-ROW($A$1)),ROW($A:$A)))`

**Case2:**

- Select the upper cell you want to return first result (vertically results).
- Press <kbd>F2</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after
  entering this formula.
- Extend the formula in below cells you want involving results.

`=INDEX(ID,SMALL(IF(AND(Hours>8,SatisfactionRate>4,AcceptanceRate>85),ROW(ID)-ROW($A$1)),ROW(A1)))`

---

### With Table

**1. Define range container Table.**

Insert-> Table

**2. Write above array form formula for table range as below**

Replace `Name` ranges with these in array formulas.

- ID -> Table1[ID]
- Hours -> Table1[Hours]
- SatisfactionRate -> Table1[SatisfactionRate]
- AcceptanceRate -> Table1[AcceptanceRate]