# Excel Formula across worksheets: If a=x, b=y then c=z

Tags: excel, formula

I started off using

```
=IF(AND(A1="this",B1="that"),"x","")
```

=IF(AND('[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$A$2=A2,'[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$B$2=B2, ???? > THEN I want it to pull the next cell '[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$C$2 into C2. So C2 would display the email address.

Hopefully if firstname & lastname match, then it pulls the email address into the new cell. Otherwise I have to manually look them up & copy & paste into the new workbook.

Comment: So you want to search a list of names and where A2 and B2 match in that list return the value in a third column in that same row?

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
=IF(AND('[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$A$2=A2,'[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$B$2=B2), '[Employee Emails.xlsx]Alpha Order'!$C$2,"")
```

Though you may also want to look into `VLOOKUP` and `INDEX/MATCH`

Answer (score 0):

If this were your data:

```
    A   B   C  D E  F G
1   A   G   1    A  G
2   B   H   2    C  I
3   C   I   3    D  K
4   D   K   4           
5   E   L   5           
6   F   M   6
```

In `G1` you'd need this array formula (applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$6,MATCH(F1&G1,$B$1:$B$6&$C$1:$C$6,0))
```

And it would produce this:

```
    A   B   C  D E  F G
1   A   G   1    A  G 1
2   B   H   2    C  I 3
3   C   I   3    D  K 4
4   D   K   4           
5   E   L   5           
6   F   M   6
```

Hopefully you'll find this helpful.