# Return a 3rd column when 2 other columns match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to return the data of a third column when two columns match.  For instance, column 1 would be "First Name" and column 2 would be "Last Name" with column 3 being their favorite color.  I tried the following as an array with no success:

```
{=if(and($A$1:$A$50=D2,$B$1:$B$50=E2),$C$1:$C$50,"")}
```

I only need the first time that column A and column B match.  Ultimately, this is like Vlookup with 2 variables.

D2 and E2 are the names to match.

Can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vlookup using 2 columns to reference another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula, which needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER...

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$50,MATCH(1,IF($A$1:$A$50=D2,IF($B$1:$B$50=E2,1)),0))
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thank you.