# Locating a specific row in a range using multiple IFs, and pulling a value from a cell at that row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset with grade-level test results, and i want to be able to track any school's grade-level progress as a grades students go to higher grades. My data is "individually" identified at the school-grade level, using school code and grade.

After identifying the row with the correct school code and grade, I want to pull that grade's test result. For some reason though, my "if" statement is not working. Any idea what could be causing the problem?

Here's my code:

```
=IF(AND(A2:A4296="0100016",B2:B4296=3),F2:F4296)
```

What I think this code should be doing is - if a row in column A has the correct school code, and that same row's column B has the correct grade, then pull that same row's value in F. But for some reason, the above IF statement is returning a FALSE value.

Comment: You may want to look into [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)

Comment: See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem since you provide no data.  Please edit your question after reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry everyone for the lack of full details. In the future I'll provide data. This time though, I was able to find a solution using the SUMIFS command.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array formula (shift, ctrl and enter) with index match will work for this.

```
{=INDEX(A2:B4296,MATCH(1,(A2:A4296="0100016")*(B2:B4296=3),0),2)}
```

Place the formula into column F.