# Excel need to find exact matches in two columns compared to two other columns in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have two worksheets with data from two different years. I have data in columns A and B in sheet 1 with names of groups (column A) and individuals (column B). I need to find all of the data in sheet 2 that matches sheet 1. For example, say in sheet 1 Row A contains company X and Row B contains individual Y. I need to find if in sheet 2 there are any instances of the exact combination of company X and individual Y.

Let me know if I need to elaborate, having trouble explaining this one

Comment: If you only need to now if that combo exists then use COUNTIFS()

Comment: I need to then either highlight those matches or preferably pull data from a third column in the second sheet

Comment: See here on how to do a two value lookup:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another