# Multiple Match criteria based on two worksheets , which contain duplicate id numbers , so need to check additional data in matched row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have two worksheets that need comparing, sheet1 has an ID code in column A , in sheet2 there are multiple duplicates of this ID number. So I need a formula to also check if the matched row data in sheet2 , also has a matched value in matched row of Sheet2.column D , with the row the formula is checking in sheet1 column G and then if matched row of Sheet2.column I , with the row the formula is checking in sheet1 column Z . If all values are added then I need to Add the value of Sheet2.Column B to where the formula is.

The formula I tried to write would be something like this , but I just can work out how to do multiple match checks

```
=INDEX('Sheet1'!$B:$B,MATCH(@'Sheet1'!$A:$A,'Sheet2'!$A:$A,0),1) and MATCH(@'Sheet1'!$G:$G,'Sheet2'!$D:$D,0),1) and MATCH(@'Sheet1'!$Z:$Z,'Sheet2'!$I:$I,0),1)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: thanks I had a look at the link , but nothing in there made sense to me , regarding my issue

Comment: how did you try using any of those formula in your situation?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: the version is office 365

Comment: i have about 35,000 rows of data in sheet1 and 250,000 rows of data in sheet2 , sheet2 has many duplicated ID numbers , which is why I needed the formula to only bring back value if all criteria is matched in additional columns. So the exact match is found. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Use the FILTER approach then.

Comment: Thanks could you kindly provide me with an example of how it should look

Comment: I did in the link above.

Comment: well I tried the filter formula but it did not wor can you please let me know what I have done wrong = FILTER('Sheet2'!A:Z,('Sheet2'!A:A='Sheet1'!A1)*('Sheet2'!D:D='Sheet1'!G1)*('Sheet2'!I:I='Sheet1'!Z1),'Sheet1'!B1)

Comment: `FILTER('Sheet2'!B:B,('Sheet2'!A:A='Sheet1'!A1)*('Sheet2'!D:D='Sheet1'!G1)*('Sheet2'!I:I='Sheet1'!Z1))`

Comment: I still get #CALC! errors

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work , but due to there being 26,000 rows to be checked and 68,000 rows of data in sheet2 . the formula takes 35 minutes to update , is there any alternative solutions in VBA

Comment: yes, look into advanced filter.

Comment: okay where is that please , is that VBA or formula

Comment: It is a built in function.  It is under the data tab.  but you can use vba to automate it.  There are many sites out there that have example code and discuss how to use it.