# Excel Index & Match vertical and horizontal criteria for copying formula

Tags: excel, indexing, match, lookup

I have been trying to populate the following table:

[image: Final_table]

with *order_amount* from the following table:

[image: Orders_table]

I cannot crack the fact there is a second condition to be taken into account - column *delivery_week*.
Can somebody please help me out with a formula so it can be used across the weeks in table *Final*?
I have tried with Index+Match. The issue is, one condition is to be looked up horizontally (product_id) and second (Deliver_week) vertically

The end result is shown here:

[image: End_state]

I would appreciate any tips..
PS: The table structure has to stay as it is - shown tables are just necessary columns to solve the problem.

Comment: use SUMIFS() function

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Answer (score 0):

In the order_amount table, try to create in D:D an assisting column which concatenates both columns A and B, i.e. (A2&B2).

Go into columns C2 in your target table and write something according the following:
(assuming order_amount is in worksheet - "sheet2")

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($A2&C$1,Sheet2!$D:$D,0),0)
```

Pull this formula to the other rows and columns to populate them, the formula is fixed, thus don't worry for changes. To replace N/A with "0" use:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,MATCH($A2&C$1,Sheet2!$D:$D,0),0),0)
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments use SUMIFS.  Put this in C2:

```
=SUMIFS(OtherSheet!$C:$C,OtherSheet!$A:$A,$A2,OtherSheet!$B:$B,C$1)
```

And copy over and down.