# How can I look up price if date falls between date range? Excel 2016

Tags: excel-formula, match, formula, array-formulas, date-range

In a spreadsheet from work, prices per product per period are tracked. I want to create a table in which I state the price per product on 1 January and 1 July for each year (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOQpC.png) for a simplified example). For this I want to look up: 'if product name matches and date fall in between date range, take over accompanying price'. For this I intend to use `INDEX+MATCH`. However, I keep getting errors after trying uncountable times.

For cell H3 (see image), I've tried using the following formula:

`=iferror(index($D$2:$D$21,match(1;($G3=$A$2:$A$21)*(H$2>=$B$2:$B$21)*(H$2<=$C$2:$C$21;0)))`

...and many variations of this formula (including small adaptation like changing `;` into `,`) in Excel 2016. I am aware that I should type `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` since it's an array formula.

Could you please help my getting the formula right so it works in Excel?

---

Now I have tried the formula `=iferror(index($D$2:$D$21;match(1;($G3=$A$2:$A$21)*(H$2>=$B$2:$B$21)*(H$2<=$C$2:$C$21);0)),"")` and still get an error. See screenshots with the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EkYi.png) and with the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZyVY.png) I get.

Any suggestions? The dates are in `mm/dd/jjjj` format now.

Comment: If your dates do not overlap per product, use SUMIFS.  See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: by the way you missed a `,` to `;`  and your `)` are off: `=iferror(index($D$2:$D$21;match(1;($G3=$A$2:$A$21)*(H$2>=$B$2:$B$21)*(H$2<=$C$2:$C$21);0)),"")`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I've now tried =iferror(index($D$2:$D$21;match(1;($G3=$A$2:$A$21)*(H$2>=$B$2:$B$21)*(H$2<=$C$2:$C$21);0)),"") and still get an error (see the edited description above). Happy with any input that may help!

Comment: I missed a `,` to `;` at the end.  you need all the `,` to be `;` or all to be `,` do not mix and match.