# If exist in range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range

I have a problem with excel!
I need to **check a list of values** and if my value **is exist between** start and end in my list , **get a price** of which one is match in list

**My product list this :**

| Id | Data | Product_Name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9905 | Mouse | $200 |
| 2 | 9915 | Power | $300 |
| 1 | 9925 | Case | $400 |

**My Price list is :**

| Id | Start | End | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9900 | 9910 | $200 |
| 2 | 9911 | 9920 | $300 |
| 3 | 9921 | 9930 | $400 |

Check **Data** in **Product list** is between **Start** and **End** in **Price list** and if **Data** is between Start and End so get me a value of Price

thhank!

Comment: a simple vlookup on the start will do it.

Comment: @ScottCraner I need to check if is between Start and End , so get me Price which one is match , vlookup do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP will do this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,H:J,3)
```

One note, make sure the lookup table is sorted ascending on the start column.

[image]

Comment: Sorry i have a question again ! can check both Data and Product_Name with VLOOKUP ?

Comment: that is a new question, and you would want to switch to SUMIFS() for that.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: No this is not a new question , In my other price list i have Product_Name and i want to check if Date is between Start and End and Product_Name is equle my Product_Name then get me Price , Can do it with VLOOKUP ?

Comment: It is a new question because you are adding conditions to the original.  This question only had to do with between start and end, no product name.  Now you are adding product name, that makes it a new question.  also the answer to your question can be found in the link I provided.

Comment: Ok i add new question and please answer this :)

Comment: Please answer this , thank:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65363654/vlookup-two-columns-in-excel