# Index Match using VBA Function in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match, countif

I'm new to Excel VBA and am trying to write a function that lets me use `INDEX`, `MATCH` and `COUNTIFS`  functions to find value for a given column by matching criteria in other columns (multiple).

I have a table named `Price` which contains some prices offered in different locations based on an assigned category:

```
Area    Category    Cost    Retail Price    Wholesale Price
USA Bad 1   13  25
Canada  Okay    2   14  26
Mexico  Good    3   15  27
USA Excellent   4   16  28
Canada  Bad 5   17  29
Mexico  Okay    6   18  30
USA Good    7   19  31
Canada  Excellent   8   20  32
Mexico  Bad 9   21  33
USA Okay    10  22  34
Canada  Good    11  23  35
Mexico  Excellent   12  24  36
```

In Excel I can use the an array formula to get this (see video example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX6UUTCMo_Y)). The below formula lets me get `Wholesale Price` for `Okay` category in `Mexico`

```
{=INDEX(Price,MATCH(1,COUNTIFS(L12,Price[Area],M12,Price[Category]),0),MATCH(N12,Price[#Headers],0))}
```

Where

```
L12 = Mexico
M12 = Okay 
N12 = Wholesale Price
```

I'd like to make a VBA function `ProdPrice` that can return this value without a messy-looking formula. Here's what I have so far:

```
Function ProdPrice(locs, cat, pricetype)
    
    'Get column number corresponding to selected "pricetype"
    col_num = WorksheetFunction.Match( _
                pricetype, _
                ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Price").HeaderRowRange.Select, _
                0)
                
    ProdPrice = WorksheetFunction.Index( _
                    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Price"), _
                    WorksheetFunction.Match( _
                        1, _
                        WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
                            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Price").ListColumns("Area").DataBodyRange.Select, _
                            locs, _
                            ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Price").ListColumns("Category").DataBodyRange.Select, _
                            cat), _
                        0), _
                    col_num)

End Function
```

Instead of a single call, I broke the function into two segments with `_` for better readability.

When I run this I get a `#VALUE!` output.

Any suggestions on how I can go about this? Also from what I understand, the above function will look for a table called `price` in the worksheet where the function is called - I'd like for it to be able to look at `price` in the workbook instead.

Comment: First argument of countifs is a range

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I changed it and still no output. I've also made some addl. changes to code - updated the post now.

Comment: Does a `SUMIFS()` formula not give you the result you’re looking for?  Something like `=SUMIFS($N:$N,$L:$L,"Mexico",$M:$M,"Okay")` (assumes `Wholesale Price` is in column `N`)

Comment: @kevin9999 Not sure I follow - could you post an answer? I also need to make sure the `category` is matched.

Comment: My comment assumes that the `country` is in column `L`, the `category` is in column `M` and the value to be summed is in column `N`.  Try and place the suggested formula in a spare cell on your sheet & let me know what result it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your values are always in an Excel structured table

Remarks:

- Function is case *insensitive*
- Table headers and values don't contain `|` character
- Function will return first matching value (`area` and `category`)
- Columns order doesn't care

Please read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**Code**

```
Public Function lookupPrice(ByVal table As Range, ByVal lookup_area As String, ByVal lookup_category As String, ByVal pricetype_header As String) As Variant
    
    ' Define column headers
    Dim areaHeader As String
    Dim categoryHeader As String
    areaHeader = "Area"
    categoryHeader = "Category"
    
    ' Get area column number from headers
    Dim areaColumn As Long
    areaColumn = Application.Match(areaHeader, table.ListObject.HeaderRowRange, False)
    
    ' Get category column number from headers
    Dim categoryColumn As Long
    categoryColumn = Application.Match(categoryHeader, table.ListObject.HeaderRowRange, False)
    
    ' Get price column number from headers according to function parameter
    Dim priceColumn As Long
    priceColumn = Application.Match(pricetype_header, table.ListObject.HeaderRowRange, False)
    
    
    ' Get area column values into 1d array
    Dim areaValues As Variant
    areaValues = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.Index(table.Columns(areaColumn), 0, 1))
    
    ' Get category column values into 1d array
    Dim categoryValues As Variant
    categoryValues = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.Index(table.Columns(categoryColumn), 0, 1))
    
    ' Define and redimension an array to hold the concatenated area and category values
    Dim areaCategoryValues() As Variant
    ReDim areaCategoryValues(1 To UBound(areaValues))
    
    ' Concatenate the area and category values and store them in an array
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To UBound(areaValues)
        areaCategoryValues(counter) = areaValues(counter) & "|" & categoryValues(counter)
    Next counter
    
    ' Get the matching row according to lookup values
    Dim resultRow As Long
    resultRow = Application.Match(lookup_area & "|" & lookup_category, areaCategoryValues, False)
    
    ' Get the result value according to the price column number
    Dim result As Variant
    result = Application.Index(table.Columns(priceColumn), resultRow)
    
    ' Return the value
    lookupPrice = result
    
End Function
```

Let me know if it works