# Excel formula to return value if two conditions are matched

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that can be pasted into cells `B2:D5` in the sheet displayed in the image below. The formula should see if the value for the row in column `A` matches a color in row `G` and if the value for the column in row `1` matches a animal in row `H`. For all cells without a two part match it should return a blank `""`. If there is a two way match then it returns the numerical value in column `I`

[image]

Comment: SUMIFS and COUNTIFS, or more inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in B2, then copy across and down:

```
=IF(SUMIFS($I$2:$I$7,$G$2:$G$7,$A2,$H$2:$H$7,B$1)=0,"",SUMIFS($I$2:$I$7,$G$2:$G$7,$A2,$H$2:$H$7,B$1))
```

Comment: This does assume that the data in the `Value` column is never `0`: note to @FinDev.

Comment: to avoid the double entry of the formula: `=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($I$2:$I$7,$G$2:$G$7,$A2,$H$2:$H$7,B$1)),"")`