# Match multiple columns in excel and then provide values in separate column

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet as following:

```
col A              col B         col C          col D          col E         col F    
67581314                         100425          153992314      1   
153992314          2              CO             67581314    
153992314          1              EC             153992314      1
```

I want to match col A with col D and col B with col E. If these both columns  has same numbers (i.e col A & col B with col D and col E), then write the col C numbers to col F for the matching numbers.

So, my output looks like following in col F

```
col A              col B         col C          col D          col E         col F    
67581314                         100425          153992314      1             EC    
153992314          2              CO             67581314                     100425    
153992314          1              EC             153992314      1              EC
```

I have tried following formulae in col F which is giving me #N/A error

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$4, MATCH(1, ($A$2:$A$4=$D2)*($B$2:$B$4=$E2),0))
```

Comment: that is an array formula, did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?  Also see here for more methods:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: Yes, I used ctrl-shift-enter

Comment: can you add a screen shot, using the data you provided, showing the formula bar and data with the cell you are getting the error selected.