# List value from different table using vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I currently have two different tables:

The first table is something like this:

| ID | Name | Course name | Course date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2213 | Bruno | CourseA | 07/05/2021 |
| 2215 | John | CourseB | 04/05/2021 |
| 2216 | Carlos | CourseB | 04/05/2021 |
| 2215 | John | CourseA | 08/05/2021 |

The second table looks like this:

| ID | Name | CourseA | CourseB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2213 | Bruno |  |  |
| 2215 | John |  |  |
| 2215 | Carlos |  |  |

My desired output is going to be like this (which is basically the second table mentioned above but now with the dates):

| ID | Name | CourseA | CourseB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2213 | Bruno | 07/05/2021 |  |
| 2215 | John | 08/05/2021 | 04/05/2021 |
| 2216 | Carlos | 04/05/2021 |  |

What is the easiest way I can do something like this?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: did you try a pivot table?

Comment: Yes, I tried but the first table I have is actually huge (more than 100k rows) and many employees are not active anymore =(  so it is very hard to filter and select the ones that I want

Comment: Then you will need to do something from my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the CourseA column:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(Table1[Course date],Table1[ID],[@ID],Table1[Course name],"CourseA")=0,"",SUMIFS(Table1[Course date],Table1[ID],[@ID],Table1[Course name],"CourseA"))
```

Then just change the string criteria for the CourseB column.

Note: This assumes no duplicate rows in Table1.

Answer (score 0):

Another option with array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,MATCH($H2&"^"&I$1,$B:$B&"^"&$C:$C,0)),"")
```

after editing confirm it with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

[image]