# Excel - Vlook up with cell value as column heder and another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Helo,

I got data like below

[image]

How I can change it into something like this ?

[image]

I've tried combinig

=IF(COUNTIF(B2;"*"&$G$1)=1;C2;"")

with VLOOKUP AND INDEX functions but with no luck...

Thank you in advance for your help

Best regards

Maciej

Comment: Are the Value1, Value2, Value3 numbers or text?

Comment: All are text:-)

Comment: here is a good guide to doing 2 value lookups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Comment: Use Powerquery for such transformations. Few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 you could achieve this using:

`=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE($B$2:$B$11)))` in `B13`

`=SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$11))` in `A14`

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=@$A$14#)*($B$2:$B$11=TRANSPOSE(@$B$13#)),0)),"")` in `B14`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect