# Find a value depending on first, what type of event it is, second, what group is playing and, finally, where it is between two dates. Excel attached

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I created a dataset to illustrate what I need help with. Its made up data so please pardon the strangeness.

[image: Example data set]

I am trying to get a value from Col E "RESULT" and get it into Col K "Result", based on data like:

```
Tennis      1        01/01/2020
Tennis      2        04/01/2021
Basketball  2        25/05/2018
Squash      2        11/09/2019
Football    1        18/02/2016
```

- The sport can vary so, that's the first variable;
- The group that plays can vary so, that's the second variable. (I've only used 2 groups to make the dataset easier to create but assume there could be up to 6 or 7 groups playing);
- Finally, the third variable, there's the date which falls between a start date and an end date (Col C and D).

I could use the lookup function to find where a date fits between two other dates but when you have 2 variables before hand, I have no idea how to deal with that.

BTW, just a final comment incase anyone asks, I don't know how to use VBA yet :/

Can anyone please help?

Comment: See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697) for examples how to do multi-column lookups.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.