# Excel get info about maximum value in a variable defined range

Tags: excel, indexing, max, maxifs

assume I have the following set of data :

```
ID CAT VAL

a   a   4

b   a   94

c   b   5

d   b   94

e   c   2

f   c   3
```

In Excel 2019 Pro get the maximum VAL of CAT=b using MAXIF(VAL,CAT=b) and I get 94. Now I want to get the ID of the corresponding value (i.e. ID=d), but I cannot use INDEX+MATCH since the maximum of CAT=a is also 94 and then I get ID=b which is not what I want.

How to get around that??

Thanks, many of them.

Comment: here are examples on how to get the result of two item lookups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: ooo yeah, thanks! used sumif(ID,CAT=b,VAL=94)

Answer (score 0):

if you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

`=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:C7,B2:B7="b"),3,-1),1,1)`

- It first filters all `CAT = B` rows.
- Sorts them by column `VAL` Descending --> the highest VAL-row is at the top
- Then returns via `INDEX` the first column of the first row.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I have Excel 2019 Pro. Edited.