# How to do simple indexing in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

[image: Simple Dataset]

See above image but I'm basically trying to get Susan's vegetable preference from the 2nd smaller "table" to the right column in the bigger table without doing it manually.  I'm working with a huge dataset, there's no way we could do it manually. What approach could I try?

This is for work, except the names are roles, and the veggies are permissions, just created this as a quick example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: In your example it's all Susan in the small table; therefore a regular VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH could work.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX($K$3:$K$5,MATCH($B3,$J$3:$J$5,0))
```

Enter into G3 and drag down