# VBA macro to give the value of a columns if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say that i have an Excel file with 3 columns and I would like that if the first two columns contains a specific word, the macro show me the value of the cell in the third column that is on the same row of the first two columns. The values of the first two columns will always be on the same rows and the first two rows cannot contain the same words.

Maybe it can work with an Excel function like an If but i struggle to make it work. If anyone has some suggestion it will be very helpful.

Thanks :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `InStr()` function combined with an `AND` statement and loop through all rows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).