# VLOOKUP matching item to UPC with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vlookup, barcode

I am attempting to use a VLOOKUP between different spreadsheet tabs to match an item to a specific UPC. I have an Excel sheet with two tabs: one is a sheet of shoes sorted by Style Number, the other is a sheet of the UPC codes that correspond to the style number.

The UPC matches specifically to a combination of the Style Number and the Size (ex: 03651698K is a separate UPC from 03651697-), but the Style Number and the Size are separate categories. I attempted to concatenate the two categories of Style Number and Size to use as a referential, but this did not change anything.

I tried utilizing VLOOKUP in several different manners, but have not had any success getting an exact match. I can get approximate matches, but the UPC does not correspond to the specific item (ex: Style 03651698K is a size 8 kids' shoe, but the approximate match gives it the UPC code of a size 15 men's shoe).

`=VLOOKUP(H7,Sheet1!$B$2:$H$2247,7,TRUE)` is the formula I am using currently.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another

Comment: That link is more confusing than the initial query

Comment: What is your excel version? With O365, you may try `XLOOKUP()` or `FILTER()` function.