# How to use VLOOKUP with exceptions?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

To assign the office responsible for a certain country I use a VLOOKUP function. In this way, Office China is responsible for Country China, Office Germany for Country Germany, etc.

[image]

There are some cases, dependent on a license, that should be assigned to other Offices, not following the VLOOKUP function.

For example:

- License6 although in Country China, should be assigned to Office Germany
- License10 although in Country China, should be assigned to Office India

There are a number of exceptions. How do I build these exceptions into the VLOOKUP function?

Comment: Use a two-column "vlookup", as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another).

Comment: Also, if you have Excel O365, that opens the door to a whole range of functions that completely simplify how you’d do this.

Comment: @BigBen : Unfortunately, I don't think it will work here, because the 2 column vlookup doesn't match. I have in one "normal" case: COUNTRY vs OFFICE. In exceptional cases - LICENSE vs OFFICE.

Comment: @MaxR : Unfortunately, I don't have Office365

Comment: Resolve the exceptions first - have them in their own lookup table. If that lookup is N/A then you run the regular rule.

Comment: So something like `="Office " & IFERROR(VLOOKUP(licenseValue,licenseLookup,2,FALSE),countryValue)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in cell `D2`:

```
=IF(A2:A100="","",IFERROR(XLOOKUP(B2:B100,TB_Exceptions[License],
TB_Exceptions[Office]), IFERROR(XLOOKUP(C2:C100,
TB_CountryOffice[Country],TB_CountryOffice[Office]), 
"CASE NOT FOUND")))
```

or using `LET` function to facilitate maintenance of the formula:

```
=LET(nameRng, A2:A100, licRng,B2:B100, countryRng, C2:C100,
 IF(nameRng="","",IFERROR(XLOOKUP(licRng,TB_Exceptions[License],
 TB_Exceptions[Office]),IFERROR(XLOOKUP(countryRng,
 TB_CountryOffice[Country],TB_CountryOffice[Office]), 
 "CASE NOT FOUND")))
)
```

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

We are using a nested `XLOOKUP` starting first with the most restricted search, i.e. the exceptions, and in case of `#N/A` then it looks for the regular country lookup table. We consider the `CASE NOT FOUND` as a last resort in case some lookup value was not defined.

We are using *Excel Tables* to have dynamic ranges in the lookup tables. For the initial data set we don't use it, because for *Excel Tables* Spilled array formulas aren't supported, i.e. it returns `#SPILL!` error.

We define the data input ranges larger than the actual input data set, in case we want to include additional data.  We add the initial condition: `IF(A2:A100="","",..)` to treat the blank lines of the input table.

Comment: Thank you! However, whatever I do, I get a message "CASE NOT FOUND"...