# Excel Index and match on multiple columns using structural referencing

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to set up an Excel formula using an index match function, where the lookup array can be in two different columns using structural referencing.

For some reasons I always get an error message on the lookup_array, which is referring to two table columns.

My formula is the following:

```
{=INDEX(Table1[Sales],MATCH(G4,Table1[Product],0),MATCH(H4,Table1[[Region 1]:[Region 2]],0))}
```

Hope someone can help me here. See also screenshot for an example case.

[image: Excel example - screenshot]

Comment: Match will only allow a 1 dimension range reference, either one column or one row.  You cannot use two columns.  This has nothing to do with Structured references, but how you are using MATCH incorrectly.

Comment: Plus, the third criterion in INDEX is not a secondary Row check.  See here on how to do multiple MATCH returns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDEX definition is: `INDEX(Range,RowRef,ColumnRef)`  You are trying to use it as `INDEX(Range,FirstRowRef,SecondRowRef)` That will not work.

Also MATCH only allows a single Row or Column and cannot look up a match in multiple columns.

In this case with office 365 I would use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Sales],(Table1[Product]=G4)*((Table1[Region 1]=H4)+(Table1[Region 2]=H4)),"")
```

That will return every one that matches the criteria.  If you only want the first then wrap it in `TAKE(...,,1)`

```
=TAKE(FILTER(Table1[Sales],(Table1[Product]=G4)*((Table1[Region 1]=H4)+(Table1[Region 2]=H4)),""),,1)
```

If one does not have OFFICE 365 then we can use `AGGREGATE` instead of `MATCH`

```
=INDEX(Table1[Sales],AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW(Table1[Product])-MIN(ROW(Table1[Product]))+1)/((Table1[Product]=G4)*((Table1[Region 1]=H4)+(Table1[Region 2]=H4))),1))
```