# Issues with multiple criteria INDEX + MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula, index-match

I am running a multiple criteria INDEX+Match, and I get N/A or it goes to the last value. I have tried to reorganize the lookup array, and it didn't work. When I try the MATCH separately, it does return the right values. The problem is when I join them.

I have a list of revenue tiers and I need to know which tier a forecast falls into. Each team has different tiers. That is the other MATCH that I am trying to add to the INDEX function.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
=MATCH(1,(B2=Sheet2!$E$4:$E$32)*(A2=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$32),0) RESULT: N/A
=MATCH(1,(B2=Sheet2!$E$4:$E$32)*(A2=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$32),1) RESULT: 29 (last value)
=MATCH(1,(B2=Sheet2!$E$4:$E$32)*(A2=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$32),-1) RESULT: N/A
```

I have rearranged it and it does not give me any different results, unfortunately.

I can attach a file with the data, if needed.

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Also see if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: Wrap each match() in iferror(), with 0 as the result and then use max(0 to find the highest value. So that would be Max(0,29,0) which will return 29.

Comment: My guess is that you are using an older version than office 365 and you need to array enter the first formula using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  And if that is not the case then you do not have any that match both criteria.

Comment: I am running Version 2208.

Comment: Then there is a good chance that none of your data meets both criteria.  You can easily test it by putting both `=(B2=Sheet2!$E$4:$E$32)` and `=(A2=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$32)` side by side in blank columns and it will spill the results.  You can then see if any row has `TRUE` in **BOTH** columns.

Comment: Could you share the screenshots of your worksheets? Also, you are playing around with the 3rd MATCH parameter i.e. what kind of match do you want to return?

Comment: The problem is coming from the revenue column. I think the match formula is looking for an exact match, and I need it to be a less than/greater than type of match, combined with the other criteria. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is looking for an exact match.  I think it time you mock up a minimal example of the data, inputs and expected output.

Comment: Two relevant screenshots: 
Forecasts: https://ibb.co/7GKdcjn
Revenue tiers: https://ibb.co/c1xdLRP

Comment: You cannot use this special kind of `MATCH` successfully with approx. matches: it is multiplying `TRUEs` and `FALSEs` and returns the first row or column index where all conditions are met (`TRUE` or 1) or an error. You could add those screenshots to your post and additionally, you should share the expected results for the given screenshots.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include all of the relevant information from the comments.

Comment: try `=MATCH(1,(B2>=Sheet2!$E$4:$E$32)*(A2=Sheet2!$B$4:$B$32),0)`

Comment: This one worked! Thank you so much!