# How to compare multiple data points in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having issues on comparing data to find matches. I'm trying to compare multiple columns to match with a single point in a row. For example A1=Bob B1= phone number C1= address then I try to compare if any of those values match in a different sheet say on D5 = Name G7= phone number J12= address. Then after comparing the data sets it out puts a match if 2 parameters are met. I was thinking that Index(Match) would be the way to go, but I'm not entirely sure. Any suggestions?

Running Index Match would only allow me to compare in one column at a time.
i.e. =index(D6:D15,match(H5,B6:B15,0))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vlookup using 2 columns to reference another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a lookup column at the end of your first dataset `A1&B1&C1...` and use index match and  `MATCH(A1&B1&c1...,'DataSet1'!X:X,0)` in your index match formula.