# How to calculate and compare values from different rows and columns with key values in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to do a calculation and then take the result and compare it to a value in a different column fpr specific keys. The example looks like this:

| Shoe Brand | Measure | Amount | Height | Is Pallet Height Correct? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adidas Shoes | BOX | 1 | 10 | Yes |
| Adidas Shoes | LAYER | 5 | 10 | Yes |
| Adidas Shoes | PALLET | 20 | 40 | Yes |
| Nike Shoes | BOX | 1 | 10 | No |
| Nike Shoes | LAYER | 6 | 10 | No |
| Nike Shoes | PALLET | 18 | 25 | No |

a PALLET's height is calculated by doing (PALLET Amount / LAYER Amount) * LAYER Height.

For the Adidas Shoes, it is calculated correctly, as (20 / 5) * 10 = 40.

However to represent this in a formula, you would need to pull the Pallet and Layer Amount, perform a calculation, and then compare it to Pallet Height all in one cell.

From my previous questions, I learned about `=IF(COUNTIF(...)`, however as far as I can tell that would not work as it requires specifying a static amount as part of the criteria.

I also saw that you can use an XLOOKUP and create some form of an array like

`=XLOOKUP([@[Shoe Brand]]&"|"&{"PALLET","LAYER"},[Shoe Brand]&"|"&[Measure],[Amount])...`

This method seems to be extremely inefficient and lags the computer. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use SUMIFS or FILTER to return the correct amount.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492758/vlookup-using-2-columns-to-reference-another/42493697#42493697

Comment: Is it OK to get the result with PowerQuery?

Comment: The goal would be to do this in one cell using a formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially your "Is Pallet Height Correct" formula would look like this (assuming your data is in a table):

```
=if(
    SUMIFS([Height],[Shoe Brand],[@[Shoe Brand]],[Measure],"PALLET")=
    (
        SUMIFS([Amount],[Shoe Brand],[@[Shoe Brand]],[Measure],"PALLET")/
        SUMIFS([Amount],[Shoe Brand],[@[Shoe Brand]],[Measure],"LAYER")*
        SUMIFS([Height],[Shoe Brand],[@[Shoe Brand]],[Measure],"LAYER")
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```