# Search a column to find if string is contained in each cell of another column, return third value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2016

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third), which gets me halfway to what I want to solve.

I've got a spreadsheet laid out like this:

- Column A has IPv4 addresses
- Column B is where I want to write my
  results.
- Column C is a set of strings that might contain IPv4
  addresses within them.
- Column D contains additional data about column
  C.

The pseduocode/logic is this:

For each cell in B, if the text of the adjacent A exists anywhere in the cells of Column C, return the text from D that is directly next to C where the match was found.

The question I linked above allows me to find exact matches and return a value, but it doesn't help me find the data in situations where the match I am looking for is inside additional text.  For example, B2 contains:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,0))
```

I suspect I need to include when referencing column C `ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))` to the formula, but I have yet to make it work.

Comment: Can you just use a wildcard in a vlookup? `=vlookup("*"&A2*"*", C:D, 2, false)`

Comment: I will give it a shot, didn't think of that.

Comment: @JNevill I think I botched your sample in a test.  I built a sample of what I'm trying to do.  [What did I do wrong?](http://imgur.com/SfOs5Al)  A2 should match on C4.

Comment: You've got a stray asterisk in there. It should look like `"*"&A2&"*"` That says: take an asterisk `"*"` and concatenate it `&` to A2 and then concatenate that `&` to another asterisk `"*"`. This will be interpreted as `*192.168.0.24*` that it will search for in column `C`

Comment: @JNevill That did the trick.  Mind making an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wildcard inside of a `vlookup` function to accomplish this:

```
=vlookup("*"&A2*"*", C:D, 2, false)
```

That says: take an asterisk `"*"` and concatenate it `&` to `A2` and then concatenate that `&` to another asterisk `"*"`. This will be interpreted as `*192.168.0.24*` that it will search for in column `C`.