# Match Column A with Column B, if value is same display with column C row data

Tags: excel

I have pulled data from two databases, and would like to match Column A data, with column B if it matches then show result in column D with the corresponding row value of column C.

**Excel Data** [image: excel data]

**What I need**:
[image: combine excel data]

If column A code matches with column B then it should show data with matched column A and corresponding column C value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If two cells match, return value from third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third)

Comment: Example are the same

Answer (score 0):

The examples are the same, but based on what you've said it's a straight up if formula
=if(a2=b2,c2,"")

Basically is a2 is the same as b2, enter in c2, otherwise nothing.