# Excel match product id from two worksheet and take the price value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two worksheets,

```
Sheet1    
ID       DESCRIPTION  COLUMN C  
AABBCC     jacket      
BBCCAA      shirt  
CCAABB      shoes


Sheet2    
 ID      PRICE  
 AABBCC     100  
 BBCCAA      50  
 CCAABB     230
```

If the id of sheet1 match with id of sheet2 extract the price from sheet2 and write in column c of sheet1

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$B$2:$B$9999, 2, FALSE)`?

Comment: @jsheeran i modified the question hope now is more clear, i tried you solution but didnt work. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Apologies, that should have been `$A$2` instead of `$B$2`. If you change that and paste it into C2 on sheet 1 it should do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If two cells match, return value from third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third)

Answer (score 0):

Or use Index and Match

In C2 put

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0)),"")
```

And drag down. Be sure to edit `$B$2:$B$4` and `$A$2:$A$4` to match your actual ranges.

Comment: let me know how it goes