# Match Column A to Column B, then output Column C from the same row as Column B

Tags: matching, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Column A is a smaller set of values from Column B. Column C is related to Column B.

You can think of this data as Countries in Columns A and B. Column C contains capital cities of countries in Column B.

I need to output correct capital cities for Column A countries by matching with Column B.

This is simiar to this question: [If two cells match, return value from third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373325/if-two-cells-match-return-value-from-third)

but I need it applied to Libre Office Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP) is the function you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you! It works. It took some time to get it to work because I was entering `FALSE` for the last parameter because my columns aren't sorted and to get a reliable error message if there are no matches, but it turns out I _had_ to enter `0` instead of `FALSE`. In the end it was `=VLOOKUP(A2;B$2:C$249;2;0)`.